# How to run only a specific mac address when running the shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

When I run the shiny app, I want to be able to run only a specific Mac address.
What kind of processing should I do?

If anyone knows, please let me know.
Also, please let me know if there is a reference web page.

Comment: Do you mean IP address? Or is this really specific to a local network situation? What operating system are you using? Maybe see: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36255/how-to-allow-only-some-specific-computer-systems-to-access-website

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I'm thinking of running it in a local environment.

The local environment means installing Rstdio and launching shiny from ui.r and server.r. I don't use shinyserver or AWS at all.

Hard-code the mac address. When you start shiny, get the mac address of the execution environment and execute it if it matches the hard-coded mac address. If they do not match, do not execute.
I would like to do the above processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have a reproducible example, you can incorporate an if statement at the beginning of your script.

```
system("getmac", intern = TRUE)
```

Will give you your local mac address.